# PHP: Code get links from X lines to Y Lines doesn't work

Tags: php, lines

This is code I used to get lines between X lines and Y lines:

```
$files = new SplFileObject($filename);
$fileIterator = new LimitIterator($files, 1800, 2000);
```

I want to get 200 lines from 1800 to 2000. However, when I print array, it shows 2000 lines. So, what wrong I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter is a count, you want `200` not `2000`

```
$fileIterator = new LimitIterator($files, 1799, 200);
```

You can check it from the [LimitIterator<sup>Doc</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/class.limititerator.php):

```
public __construct ( Iterator $iterator [, int $offset = 0 [, int $count = -1 ]] )
```

Also consider that `offset` starts from 0, so if you want the `1800th` line, you need to use `1799`

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the documentation you can see that the second parameter is a count and not the ending line.

```
public __construct ( Iterator $iterator [, int $offset = 0 [, int $count = -1 ]] )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.limititerator.php

```
$fileIterator = new LimitIterator($files, 1800, 200);
```

So you need something like this.